# How to create amr file from raw amr frames?

Tags: ffmpeg, sox, amr

Is there a way to create AMR file from raw AMR frames with ready to use tools such as `ffmpeg` or `sox`?

Let’s say I have frames in files like so `1.bin 2.bin 3.bin`. Can I create AMR file from them, somehow? I’ve searched on how to do that with ffmpeg but found nothing.